# In Java 11 HttpClient how to solve restricted header name: Date

Tags: java, http, java-11, java-http-client

The following java 11 code:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(uri)
            .header("Digest", digest)
            .header("Date", date)  
            .build();
```

gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: restricted header name: "Date"
```

The problem is that the digest is based on the date, so I cannot simply rely on the http client date, because that will make the digest invalid.
I need a way to either set the Date header, or to retrieve the Date header and then set the digest thereafter. Neither seems possible with standard java 11.

Comment: In the example both digest and date are strings, so that’s not the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Bug#[JDK-8213189](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213189)

This is a bug registered in current JDK's http-client implementation where `Date`
is categorized as a *restricted header* as well.

In JDK/12, there would be a provision for other such restricted headers to be allowed using the attribute:

```
-jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders
```

Comment: According to this it is fixed in version 12. Oh well, since I already skipped version 9 and 10 I might as well skip 11!

Comment: But JDK 12 is not a LTS version.